# extracting a location from a list with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list like so

```
x=['hello@thepowerhouse.group', 'ThePowerHouse\xa0 is a part of the House of ElektroCouture', 'Our Studio is located at Bikini Berlin Terrace Level, 2nd floor Budapester Str. 46 10787 Berlin', '\xa0', 'Office:\xa0+49 30 20837551', '\xa0', '\xa0']
```

I want to extract the this element `Our Studio is located at Bikini Berlin Terrace Level, 2nd floor Budapester Str. 46 10787 Berlin'`

Since I am doing this for several sites I want to extra the element with regular expressions so it can work with others. I thought that I could grab the element by saying if the element has lower case and upper case letters, numbers , commas , and sometimes a period. This is what I attempted but it didn't work.

```
import re
for element in x:
    if re.findall("([A-Za-z0-9,])",element)==True:
        print("match")
```

Comment: Not the way to go. Can't rely on the element content. And, really, you need to parse a delimited element as well.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, you already have the elements. Still you cant rely on the content characters to get an _address_. And to verify that the element has all/most of those chars, you have to use individual assertions `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*,)`, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up your rule into several simple regexes and test them in sequence instead of making some monster-expression.

```
import re

def is_location(text):
    """Returns True if text contains digits, uppercase and lowercase characters."""
    patterns = r'[0-9]', r'[a-z]', r'[A-Z]'
    return all(re.search(pattern, text) for pattern in patterns)

x = [
    'hello@thepowerhouse.group',
    'ThePowerHouse\xa0 is a part of the House of ElektroCouture',
    'Our Studio is located at Bikini Berlin Terrace Level, 2nd floor Budapester Str. 46 10787 Berlin',
    '\xa0', 'Office:\xa0+49 30 20837551', '\xa0', '\xa0'
]

print(next(filter(is_location, x)))
```

Comment: what does next do?

Comment: It's a python builtin function. It just extracts the first entry from the iterator object returned from `filter()`. `next()` is what's used under the hood in `for` loops. It's not essential here.

Comment: I see, what if I want all the answers given?

Comment: Then you can use `list(filter(is_location, x))`, for example. You can also use a list comprehension: `[a for a in x if is_location(a)]`